# How does the +1 Keen Composite Longbow (+2 Str) work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons

I would like to know how the +1 Keen Composite Longbow (+2 Str) from the dragon's demand works.

I already understand the keen rule, however, I don't know how to apply the bonuses.

My character has a score of 8 in Str (-1), and I understand that this +2 Str bonus plus 2 points to Str score to get 10 gives me a +0, right? Also, does this bonus work for everything (e.g. my abilities), or just when I use the Longbow?

On the other hand, does the +1 get 1 additional to my base attack only, or 1 additional for the damage too? Does this +1 work for all my attacks (e.g.  if I get 3 attacks per round)? I'll appreciate if you can give me an example.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 20):

A *[composite longbow](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/longbow-composite/) +2 Str* doesn't give you increased Str, it *requires* +2 Str. Your 8 Str character will be greatly penalized:

> All composite bows are made with a particular Strength rating (that is, each **requires a minimum Strength modifier to use** with proficiency). If your Strength bonus is less than the strength rating of the composite bow, you can’t effectively use it, so **you take a –2 penalty on attacks with it**. The default composite longbow requires a Strength modifier of +0 or higher to use with proficiency. A composite longbow can be made with a high strength rating to take advantage of an above-average Strength score; this feature allows you to add your Strength bonus to damage, up to the maximum bonus indicated for the bow. Each point of Strength bonus granted by the bow adds 100 gp to its cost. **If you have a penalty for low Strength, apply it to damage rolls when you use a composite longbow.**

You will thus suffer a -2 attack penalty when using this bow, and a -1 damage penalty.

However, it's a +1 weapon (+1 to attack and damage with all attacks made using the bow).

Overall, this means you suffer a -1 attack penalty and +0 damage, compared to a regular non-composite longbow. In other words, other than the *keen* property, this is overall worse for your 8 Str character than a normal longbow.

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108400/can-the-strength-bonus-of-a-composite-bow-be-improved

Comment: That being said, if OP foresees increasing his ability score, it may be worthwhile to hang onto the bow for when they can use it better.

Comment: It may be worth adding that [Keen](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/keen/) only benefits "piercing or slashing **melee** weapons"; it's not part of the question but seems like good information to include for OP.

Comment: @Ifusaso Oh, true. A [Paizo forum thread](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2quit?Keen-Composite-Longbow-in-Dragons-Demand) confirms that this item does exist in Dragon's Demand as a unique item even though it cannot normally be crafted (presumably an error, but they let it stand, and presumably this relates the intent is that it works as expected).